# Informal Book/Material Recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I have started reading measure theory and encountered a topic Hausdorff measure. I find this topic quite interesting. However, some texts that I am going through Rudin and Folland are too formal and I want to avoid mathematical technicalities for the time being.

Can you please recommend some texts, a bit informal and intuitive in this regard.

**Edit** Honestly, I find it very difficult to follow Rudin, and Folland, a kind of preparation, not enjoying at all. Some books that I have are heavily emphasized on Lebesgue Measure. Whatever I am left with are too obsessed with set theoretic treatment (P. R Helmos). I really want to learn this subject and apply it in various mathematical machinery. For that thing I first need to learn *why?* *what?* *How?* informally. Please help me!!! I may sound dull, you may can down vote this. If possible, close this too. But please help me with this subject (by suggesting me a bit stimulating text, Some lecture series will be nice too).

Comment: In English Geradl Edgard's book Integral, Probability and Fractal Measures is a nice place to go; Falconer's Fractal Geometry is a classic too.

Comment: Is it informal! Or focused on mathematical rigor! I want to avoid mathematical technicalities for the tie being.@OliverDiaz

Comment: They are rigorous; Edgard's however has plenty of good examples that will sow you the why, how , etc. If you don't have a good background in analysis, then they may seem advance to you.

Comment: I have a basic course on analysis and definitely try this book@OliverDiaz

Comment: However, If there are any other informal expository, you can recommend them@OliverDiaz

Comment: Falconer also has a nice book without much fancy mathematics: Fractals: A Very Short Introduction (Very Short Introductions). That may give you good ideas. Of course, you can check Benoit B. Mandelbrot books on fractals.

Comment: I have never studied Hausdorff measure in detail, but I think it is very unlike to find a non-rigorous account on the topic. This is advanced mathematics, which has abstract theories such as measure or set theory as a pre-requisite. However, different books have different rigor and some of them can give the reader some geometrical intutiton together with the rigorous/formal exposure of the topic. Maybe you can find other intuitive/geometrical resources on the internet (e.g. wikipedia) where the exposure aims a more broad audience.

Comment: Also, I personally don't see how you will be able to apply it to other areas of mathematics by understanding it informally. But, on the other hand, I understand that geometric meaning can be helpful to develop some intuition on what is behind all the abstraction of some theory.

Comment: Actually, I need a bit intuitive treatment for the time being and get a space to think by myself. However, mathematical rigor at the starting feels like a force@IamWill

Comment: I also agree with you@IamWill, that I will not be apply it by learning it completely informally. I do have plans to continue with mathematical rigors. I said for the time being, to develop intuition, to ask why?, I need book suggestions.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz: Did you mean [**Measure, Topology, and Fractal Geometry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387747486) by Edgar, which was (originally) published in 1990, 7 years before his much more advanced book [**Integral, Probability, and Fractal Measures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387982051) was published? Also, pmun --- maybe [**Lectures on Fractals and Dimension Theory**](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbl/dimension-total.pdf) by Mark Pollicott (April-May 2005, 106 pages) could be of use (probably too advanced for detailed study now, but might be useful for motivation and applications).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: you are right. I have both in my personal library and I can't remember one from the other. (I have not open them in quite some time, but I remember perusing thought  both and liking them). Maybe GEdgard himself can chime it and give a recommendation.

Comment: Thankyoy@DaveL.Renfro for your suggestions and Thankyou@Oliver Diaz for being so responsive.

Comment: I recommend Stein and Shakarchi's volume on real analysis, including measure theory and integration as an alternative to Folland or Rudin, both of which are great books in their own right.

Comment: I mainly used Rudin and Folland for real analysis (the beginning parts of Rudin and later parts of Folland), but neither of them covers Hausdorff measure in detail. Stein and Shakarchi as mentioned by Alex Oritz is also a good book; it has a more bottom-up approach rather than top-down as in Rudin and Folland, and the writing felt more conversational. Just FYI: Folland also has a book "A Guide to Advanced Real Analysis". This is a much more informal book than his real analysis text, and in places he explains the ideas and the heuristics of the proofs.

Comment: I found this more informal nature of the book helpful, because what I would do was read the relevant chapters in this book (which felt like a storybook to me) and then after gaining some rough perspective, I would be in much better shape to read his real analysis text, and I could also digest the rigorous material much quicker. Just to be clear: in Folland's exposition is more relaxed here, but the definitions and statements of theorems are given carefully. The proofs are sketched briefly, but if it is too technical to efficiently summarize he skips it, and gives appropriate references

Comment: I was looking for such kind of references!Thank you@peek-a-boo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Stein and Shakarchi's volume on real analysis, including measure theory and integration as an alternative to Folland or Rudin, both of which are great books in their own right. Stein's technical writing is second to none. This volume in particular includes a chapter on Hausdorff measure and fractals.

Google scholar reference:

> Stein, Elias M., and Rami Shakarchi. Real analysis: measure theory, integration, and Hilbert spaces. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Comment: Thank you @Alexortriz for your answer